# How can I exclude particular names from Get-ADComputer results?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get all computers in my domain that are enabled, and have 2003 operating system, and the name of the computers do Not contain ' ping , pict , pire '
Here is what I have, but totally failing:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -and (OperatingSystem -like "*2003*")} -properties OperatingSystem | where {($_.Name -notlike 'PING*') -or ($_.Name -notlike 'PICT*') -or ($_.Name -notlike 'PIRE*')} | Select Name
```

Comment: What do you get when you change `-or` to `-and` (both of them)?

Comment: Define "failing". What result do you get, and how does that differ from the result you expected?

Comment: Your conditions should be `-and` since PICT001 would match the condition `($_.Name -notlike 'PING*')` making that part of the condition True which would satisfy the `-or`. Also you could simplify this with a little regex: `Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch "^(PING|PICT|PIRE)"}` or `-notmatch "^PI(NG|CT|RE)"}`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-notlike` operator inside the filter, so there is no need for the `where` statement. See the [Get-ADComputer reference on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx).

As well as changing your `-or` operators to `-and` as I mentioned, I put all conditions into the filter ending up with this:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {
   Enabled -eq $True -and
   OperatingSystem -like '*2003*' -and
   Name -notlike 'PING*' -and
   Name -notlike 'PICT*' -and
   Name -notlike 'PIRE*'
} | Select Name
```